# Opening Certain Sites in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, internet, ssl

I Searched a lot about this Question and no answer could help me :(
My problem is in connect to certain sites in Ubuntu 14.04 (Specially SSL connections mostly with Error 100 (Connection was reset))! Java Scripts Also not working properly! I update my fire fox But it not works!
I have a windows 7 along side my Ubuntu, But in it All website connects without any problem!

for example Online Banks not opens in ubuntu But opens in Windows!

Can Anybody help me with this issue? It makes me mad!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 100 :-
100 Continue
This means that the server has received the request headers, and that the client should proceed to send the request body (in the case of a request for which a body needs to be sent; for example, a POST request). If the request body is large, sending it to a server when a request has already been rejected based upon inappropriate headers is inefficient. To have a server check if the request could be accepted based on the request's headers alone, a client must send Expect: 100-continue as a header in its initial request and check if a 100 Continue status code is received in response before continuing (or receive 417 Expectation Failed and not continue).

run firefox in safe mode and check again!!

Comment: Tahnks dear Tohid.
You right about error 400! But it's noy my only problem in ubuntu! my git also not working while in my windows 7 alongside ubuntu it workd very vell! Can you help me with that? thanks.

Comment: will you give a try to chromium and tell me the results?

Comment: dear @Tohid Tamboli I installed Chromium and test.'
But problem resists yet :(
looks like something in my UBUTNU went wrong! :(

Comment: ` sudo ufw disable ` it will turn off ur Ubuntu firewall and then try for the special sites.

Comment: Thanks @Tohid
I can't test this yet! Because that problem happens sometimes! But is it not dangerous to disable the firewall??
----
Another problem still resist in javaScript Requests, And I cant use like buttons in some websites like: www.researchgate.net.
Google Chrome Shows this error!
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: Also this error on firefox console:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at